# itunes Connect build status is processing since a long time and then error:ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app with version 1.2.1 and build version 1.0.
The app has been successfully uploaded to iTunes connect,But it was showing processing since a long time and after that its showing a red badge over with some error:ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed

Should I upload a new version of app or there is any solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting such problem try this options:

- If it took few hours than wait for at least 2-3 days. This might be occur because apple server is busy or an inbuilt issue from Apple site or they might be working on the site silently.
- If even after 3 days it shows similar status than prepare new build with Same version number & just changing Build number.

**Note:**

- I had faced this issue 2 times during different app uploads.
- I was getting processing failed status & it was in process for few hours
- I just waited for 1 day & on next day when i checked error gone automatically & it will ready for submit.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. So I tried to upload build using ***Application Loader*** and it works.